# SPSS don't "see" date format

Tags: spss, forecasting

I load my dataset in SPSS to do the forecast.Example of data.

```
Data_          x1            x2
1 oct 2017  3750,179792 11488,58111
2 oct 2017  3846,066274 11984,01865
3 oct 2017  3894,418165 12265,66877
4 oct 2017  4009,801974 12800,94833
5 oct 2017  4146,703036 13290,94974
6 oct 2017  4334,559128 13828,14324
7 oct 2017  4554,119797 14273,26226
8 oct 2017  4744,258115 14664,35602
9 oct 2017  4884,630434 15130,4423
10 oct 2017 5019,520503 15851,40231
11 oct 2017 5207,792904 16508,50631
```

[Here my dataset in SPSS screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Dwk.png)

[dataset var tab screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t48Ze.png)

So i go to `Analyze-Forecasting-Create models`, but in option tab, i can't set day for forecast i.e `28 oct 2017`(look at red arrow)
so i can't do this forecast.

what do I need to do so, that I can specify the date for forecast

Answer (score 0):

Your date data is in text format - you need to create an actual date variable to use in the analysis. 
Use this in syntax:

```
COMPUTE DateVar=number(Data_ , DATE11).
FORMATS DateVar (DATE11).
EXECUTE.
```

Or follow through the Date and Time Wizard found in the Transform menu.

Comment: dear, @eli-k ,  i tried do it during two days, but after script, I still can not  specify the date for forecast, here the screen https://imgur.com/a/nbUg1. Can you help me?

Comment: in this image you didn't check the "specified date" option